# What is the best way to design dynamic object that is updated in realtime?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, architecture

I've got a problem that I'm trying to solve from sometime. Say that there is a web application with a page that has many input fields. Assume that there are many concurrent users accessing this page and entering data in said inputs.When one user edits a field that change should be reflected in all the other users interfaces. Can someone point me in the right direction or any web resources to get this done. Also currently there are two load balanced tomcat nodes hosting the web application and I have a thought of creating a common dynamic object to hold the data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: 'Real time' has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn't it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Thanks EJP, could you help me correct this. What is the correct term for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more an architectural one. How to you automatically update a second GUI upon actions in GUI #1?

You probably know how to forward the action to one of your tomcat instances. The first problem is how to broadcast this action to all server instances. You could write it to a database and let every instance poll regularly, but that would be poor design. You probably need to persist your data, but if you need to let all instances know about updates, I suggest to use a messaging queue (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#JMS-Provider).

Part two of your problem is how to push the updates back to all browsers. There have been quite a few frameworks to achieve this. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming). Java 9 supports a brand new technology you could use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket. The quick-and-dirty solution would be a javascript polling regulary.

You basically have to decide between the easy polling and the more advanced pushing technologies both on the server and client side.

You could also choose NOT to implement it yourself at all and use something like that: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html.